# Layout Break when using single-spa micro frontend with vue and reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, micro-frontend

I have a problem in my single-spa project, I don't know why but sometimes my single-spa break the layout like sometimes header in the bottom and the content above it, or the content below the footer.

for you who doesn't know what single-spa, you can read in here: https://single-spa.js.org/docs/examples

this is my registration apps:

```
import { registerApplication, start } from "single-spa";
import * as isActive from "./activity-functions";

registerApplication(
  "@vue-mf/vue-navbar",
  () => System.import("@vue-mf/vue-navbar"),
  isActive.vueNavbar
);

registerApplication(
  "@vue-mf/rate-dogs",
  () => System.import("@vue-mf/rate-dogs"),
  isActive.vueComponent
);

registerApplication(
  "@react-mf/people",
  () => System.import("@react-mf/people"),
  isActive.reactComponent
);

registerApplication(
  "@vue-mf/vue-footer",
  () => System.import("@vue-mf/vue-footer"),
  isActive.vueFooter
);

start();
```

and this is my activity function:

```
export function prefix(location, ...prefixes) {
  return prefixes.some(
    prefix => location.href.indexOf(`${location.origin}/${prefix}`) !== -1
  );
}

export function vueNavbar(location) {
  // The navbar is always active
  return true;
}

export function vueComponent(location) {
  return prefix(location, "rate-doggos");
}

export function reactComponent(location) {
  return prefix(location, "people");
}

export function vueFooter(location) {
  // The footer is always active
  return true;
}
```

for better visualization, this is the example of the layout break:

[image: this show you the break when content is above the navbar]

[image: this show you the content below footer]

[image: this is what i want where content in the middle of navbar and footer]

I'm using single-spa with `vue` & `react`

can someone help me to solve this? I'm quite confused about this layout break

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I would guess that this is the result of asynchronously loading each of the apps and that the render order would depend on which app was returned first.

It looks like Joel Denning realized this and has created a Layout Engine to deal with it:  https://single-spa.js.org/docs/layout-overview.

However, it's still in beta and I'm finding that there's still some limitations with it but perhaps it would suit your needs.